# How can you take a function as a parameter and call it?

Tags: python, calculator

My task is the following: "Write a function named operate that takes as parameters 2 integers named a, b and a function named func which that takes 2 integers as parameters. Also write the functions `add`, `sub`, `mul`, and `div` that take 2 integer parameters and perform the operation corresponding to their name and print the result. Calling `operate(a, b, func)` should result in a call to `func(a, b)`". I've done the first four parts, but I'm stuck on how to implement `operate`. Here is my code so far:

```
# this adds two numbers given
def add(a,b):
    print (a + b)

# this subtracts two numbers given
def sub(a,b):
    print (b - a)

# this multiplies two numbers given
def mul(a,b):
    print (a * b)

# this divides two numbers given
def div(a,b):
    print (a / b)
```

Comment: Show us what you wrote so far, and what result it produced.

Comment: We're not a coding service -- we don't do your work for you. Rather, StackOverflow exists to be a canonical repository of questions and answers. So -- try to figure out *why* you're stuck, extract a specific question from that, search on the site for an answer, and *then* ask a question that complies with the [Help Center's guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is the standard library prohibited? Can you do `from operator import add, sub, mul, (truediv|floordiv) as div`?

Comment: @ShanAli, [edit] your code into the question rather than leaving it in a comment.

Comment: Check the post.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen not sure it is a challenge from my fellow friend he is a instructor in university

Comment: @ShanAli Thanks for updating - however you've still not quite got a "specific" question. Is there anything going wrong with this code? What have you tried with regards to `operate`, and why didn't it work? Also, is there a reason `sub` is in reverse order?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen   *Write a function named operate that takes as parameters 2 integers named a, b and a **function named func which that takes 2 integers*** as parameters*. I m not able to understand it actually how to code it.

Comment: @ShanAli Yes, that's what the task is, but it's not a question about the nature of programming in Python. Could you tell us what you've tried/researched and why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to `return` something from your functions, not just print something. This lets you use the result later. To do this just use the `return` statement with some expression:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def sub(a, b):
    return a - b 

def mul(a, b):
    return a * b 

def div(a, b):
    return a / b
```

I've changed the order of your `sub` operation to be more in line with how subtraction is generally defined.

To now write an `operate` function is actually pretty easy. You've been given two parts already: the signature should be `operate(a, b, func)` and you should call `func(a, b)`. This is actually almost all of what it will end up as - all you need to do is again `return` it (you could also `print` it here if you wanted):

```
def operate(a, b, func):
    return func(a, b)
```

You can now do something like this:

```
print(operate(3, 2, add))
print(operate(3, 2, sub))
print(operate(3, 2, mul))
print(operate(3, 2, div))
```

Which will result in the output:

```
5
1
6
1.5
```

In a comments I asked about the standard library - you see, all of these are already implemented by Python. You can replace the first four function definitions with this:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv as div
```

Leaving you to only define `operate` and do some testing.